# Redirect old multi-blog to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect one blog from an old multi-blog site (with a terrible url) to a new version, on a new domain.

old site: http://campaigns.emcoutdoor.com/blogs/index.php?blog=4

new site: http://www.emcoutdoor.com/campaigns/

not concerned about the indiviual pages - just want anything on there to go to the main page for the new site.

I've tried a bunch of htaccess redirect codes, but not getting it to work - any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running the old website on an Apache server. Have you tried to put an `.htaccess` file in your old website **DocumentRoot**, with this directive:

```
RedirectMatch permanent .* http://www.emcoutdoor.com/campaigns/
```

If you did, but this doesn't do anything (or worse generates an internal server error), check that the `alias_module` Apache module is loaded - eg on Linux you can get a list of loaded modules using the shell command:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^campaigns\.emcoutdoor\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^blog=4(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|)$ http://www.emcoutdoor.com/campaigns/? [L,R=301,NC]
```